# How to plot ageing vector graph as the paper showed?

Tags: r, vector, graph, visualization, lme4

I'm trying to plot a graph like this one from a paper [The reference](https://bmcpublichealth.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12889-022-12671-6). This graph shows how global cognition (the dependent variable) of people with different baseline ages decline(direction and rate) over the 7 years of follow-up.

The dataset is a panel data. In this paper, it fitted the trajectory of global cognition first using Latent growth curve modelling.

However, I have no idea how to extract the information for the direction and rate. Can anyone provide some suggestion?

I search for tutorial with the key word "ageing vector graph". But I didn't get the results I needed.

I have fitted a mixed effect model with lmer() function. I guess its coefficients could provide information to plot each vector.

[image]

Comment: Could we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31095291/6851825 or this? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/99049/221905

Comment: Many thanks your reply! I've solved this issue.

Comment: If you've solved the issue, you should either post an answer (if you think it could be useful to future readers) *or* delete your question (if you think the answer won't be useful)